# First installation and start up problem

Tags: 14.04

1st & foremost, this is my very first question and I am not that good with standard forum procedures, so please be patient with me.

The Ubuntu is 14.04Lts

after 3 or 4 re-installs I have got the pc to begin to the page immediately after the password log in.

I did, to begin with, have to revise the standard graphics card driver for one of the 3 Nvidia drivers shown as an option.

doing the above has given me a stable visual...BUT

as stated above I have only an empty page after the password log-in page [i.e.  no icons at all].

If the pc is left for circa 15 minutes the pc goes black blank [with an operable mouse] and eventually goes back to the log in password page again.

The only other thing that I don't understand is at the beginning of start up  a message comes up before any of the above stating:
[661524 ACPI failed] this may be different numbers [i.e. 657468 etc]

I have no idea if that is relevant, but at this stage I cannot get started with the Ubuntu OS.

any help/advice would be well appreciated.

MrU